# CKEditor only show dialog window once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Hello I have been stuck on this for the past day.
I made a plugin for the CKEditor, when a user clicks the record button, a dialog opens up with language selection. Once the user selects the language they begin recording their speech. The problem is when the user ends the speech recognition and they want to record sometime later they are again prompted by the dialog window to select a language again. I want to make it so when the user selects a language and they click record, the dialog window doesn't pop up again.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('speechtotext', { 
    init: function(editor) {

        editor.ui.addButton('RecordButton', {
            label: 'Speech to Text',
            command: 'record',
            toolbar: 'insert',
        });

        //Button to end recording
        editor.ui.addButton('StopButton', {
            label: 'End Speech to Text',
            command: 'stop',
            toolbar: 'insert',
        });
        //Command to end Speech to Text Recording
        editor.addCommand('stop', {
            exec: function() {
                //stopRecording();
            }
        });

        //Register the "recordDialog", returns the Dialog object
        CKEDITOR.dialog.add('recordDialog', function() {
            //The definition of the Dialog(the dialog window itself).
            return {
                title: 'Speech to Text Language Selection',
                contents: 
                [{
                    elements: 
                    [{
                        type: 'select',
                        id: 'languageSelect',
                        label: 'Select Language',
                        items: 
                        [
                            //items
                        ],
                        default: 'english',
                        onChange: function() {
                            languageOption = this.getValue();
                            console.log(languageOption);

                            languageSelected = true;
                        } 
                    }]
                }],
                //The code that will execute ok button of the dialog window is pressed.
                onOk: function() {
                    //start recording(){}
                }
            };
        });

        if(languageselected === false){
            //opens up dialog window to prompt user for language selection
            editor.addCommand('record', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('recordDialog'));
        }else{
            editor.addCommand('record', {
                exec: function() {
                    //startrecording without prompting user to select language again
                }
            });
        }

    }
});
```

Whenever i select a language i say languageSelected = true;
so that next time i'm not prompted for another language selection but this does nothing its like it never runs.
I'm starting to think that maybe I somehow have to destroy the plugin instance and reload it again so that next time it calls the 'record' command without the dialog.

```
if(languageSelected === false){
   //opens up dialog window to prompt user for language selection
   editor.addCommand('record', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('recordDialog'));
}else{
  editor.addCommand('record', {
        exec: function() {
        //startrecording without prompting user to select language again
        }
  });
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working? Thanks!

Comment: My guess, you declared `languageSelected = true` in function scope, invisible from outside. ( Also  just in case, in you code above `languageselected === false` languageselected is not in camelCase ). But from your code, i can't understand why in condition else is not executed always.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the issue fixed by overriding the 'record' command  this way i don't call the one that opens up the dialog next time i click the record button.